# Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'

Tags: c++, char

I'm making a program to convert singular nouns to plural nouns. I'm very new to coding, and I keep getting the error on line 44 of my code that I made an "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*". Also, on line 41, I'm getting the "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*". I'm not entirely sure what this means or how to fix it?. I'm using NetBeans with C++, here is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>



    #define max_word 20



    void pluralize (char word[]);


    int main (void)
    { 
      char noun[max_word];   /* stores temporary word entered by user */

      printf("Enter a noun in singular form: ");
      scanf("%s", noun);

      while (strcmp(noun, "done") != 0)
     {
        pluralize (noun);
        printf("The plural form is %s\n", noun);
     }
    }

    void pluralize (char word[])
    {
      int length;
      char noun;
      length=1;
      length = strlen(word);

    for (;;) 
    {
        printf("Enter a noun in singular form: ");
        scanf("%s", noun);

        if ((strcmp( noun, "done") == 0))
            break;

        pluralize (noun);
        printf("The plural form is %s\n", noun);
    }
      return;
    }
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", noun);`...watch there....

Comment: and then, `(strcmp( noun, "done") `....

Comment: This isn't C++, it's C. Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Oops, I just removed the C tag because "*I'm using NetBeans with C++*". This looks like valid C++ to me.

Comment: So, how are we supposed to know what's line 44?  Do you expect us to count lines?

Comment: `char noun[max_word];` in one function vs. `char noun;` in another. Spot the difference.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that this hadn't included the line count. 41 is "if ((strcmp( noun, "done") == 0))" and 44 is "pluralize (noun);"

Comment: @Etienne The OP clearly states that this is a C++ program, regardless of idiom. Please do not accept bad edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In pluralize function, noun is a char, it means one character. You want a char array here like in your main :

```
char noun[max_word];
```

This compiles without error.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, except the `char*` will have to be initialised to point to some buffer. The OP should actually use `std::string` since (despite silly would-be moderators forcing the OP to change the question tag incorrectly) they're writing C++.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I deleted my comments because they no longer apply and the answer was fixed.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Well, I think you don't know what the difference between an array and a pointer is.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Huh. We're probably talking past each other. I just can't figure out where the split is.

Comment: @melpomene: Well, it doesn't matter now.